# How to customize google chrome tab hover cards

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-flags

Is there any workaround to customize the tab hover card of chrome 78+?
By customize I mean to change the text of the hover card.

The page was opened blank and then html text is added using write function. Then I changed the title.

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.write(htmlText);
win.document.title = htmlFileName
```

My actual problem is, when I hover a tab it shows '*Loading...*' instead of the actual title(value of `htmlFileName`).

*"I know that it is not a good move to ask the user to set the chrome flag tab-hover-cards to disabled"
Also, the solution should support ie9+*

Comment: update: `window.stop();`, `document.close();` didn't work.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Though this issue is more than 1 year old. Still I would like to suggest a solution. Please try the below:

```
var win = window.open("about:blank");
win.document.write(htmlText);
win.document.title = htmlFileName
```

Adding `"about:blank"` inside `window.open` will show the title of the page on tab hover card instead of "loading...."

Answer (score 0):

Adding win.document.close() doesnt keep the tab in the loading state.

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.write("<html>Hi</html>");
win.document.title = "Testing";
win.document.close();
```

The above piece of code worked for me.

Comment: Sorry to say this. Didn't work. tab hover card still shows 'Loading... '.